# Split one column by rows to multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix

I am working in Excel 2013, and I have data like the following:

A1

A2

A3

B1

B2

B3

(The As go to A13, Bs go to B13, Cs go to C13, and so on until you get to row 2495.)

How do I divide this long column where the 14th row moves to the next column? See below:

A1  B1  C1  ...and so on

A2  B2  C2

A3  B3  C3

...

A13 B13 C13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B1:  =INDEX($A:$A,(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*13+ROWS($1:1))
```

- Fill right to AA1
- Select B1:AA1 and fill down to row 13

The above assumes you are going `A-Z`.  But you must have other characters also in order to get to 2495 rows.  Your real data may require some tweaks from what I have presented -- either filling down further; or filling further to the right, or using a different constant then `13`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the data into three  separate columns then in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **C1** enter:

```
=A14
```

In **D1** enter:

```
=A27
```

Then copy these three cells downwards:

[image]